# How to fix [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long ERROR?

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, package, oserror

I'm facing this error while installing the setup for Tensorflow Object Detection API. How to fix this error?

````
Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long: ```
````

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Error: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [WinError 206] The filename or extension is too long:`

To fix this error on your Windows machine on `regedit` and navigate to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem` and edit `LongPathsEnabled` and set value from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0):

hi check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obJmcid_erI. i use method 1.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).