# Why is the subprocess.Popen argument length limit smaller than what the OS reports?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, command-line-arguments

I am running Python 3.4.3 on Linux 3.16.0. I want to use `subprocess.Popen` to run a command with a long single argument (a complex Bash invocation), roughly 200KiB.

According to `getconf` and `xargs`, this should be well within my limits:

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
2097152
$ xargs --show-limits < /dev/null
Your environment variables take up 3364 bytes
POSIX upper limit on argument length (this system): 2091740
POSIX smallest allowable upper limit on argument length (all systems): 4096
Maximum length of command we could actually use: 2088376
Size of command buffer we are actually using: 131072
```

However, Python fails with quite smaller limits:

```
>>> subprocess.Popen('echo %s > /dev/null' % ('a' * (131072-4096)), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7f4613b58410>
>>> subprocess.Popen('echo %s > /dev/null' % ('a' * (262144-4096)), shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  [...]
OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long
```

Note that the Python limit is roughly the same as the "actually using" command buffer `xargs` reports. This suggests that `xargs` is somehow smart enough to start with a smaller limit and increase it as needed, but Python is not.

Questions:

1. Why is the Python limit smaller than the OS limit of 2MiB?
2. Can I increase the Python limit?
3. If so, how?

Comment: Don't use the "single string" API of `subprocess.Popen()`. Always pass a list instead. Avoid `shell=True`.

Comment: In this case, I'm actually relying on Bash features in the subprocess.

Comment: Try `subprocess.Popen('echo $SHELL')`. I think that will give you `/bin/sh`, not bash.

Comment: Just because ARGMAX shows 2097152 does not mean that is, try `131071` and `131072`

Comment: @AaronDigulla That's why I added `executable='/bin/bash'`. :)

Comment: @Reid, any reason you aren't passing the script on stdin rather than in an argument?

Comment: @Charles, yes, the reason is that it's a lot easier to coordinate a command line argument than a writable `stdin`.

Comment: I'm not sure I accept that assertion; the subprocess module makes it pretty darned trivial, if one is letting it do the work.

Comment: You need to get into pipes or temporary files, flush appropriately, avoid deadlocks, deal with streaming the output (`communicate()` is inappropriate for my use case), etc. Anyway, this line of discussion is off topic for this question. Please take it to chat or open your own question.

Comment: zlib.compress(optionstr)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The maximum size for a single string argument is limited to 131072. It has nothing to do with python:

```
~$ /bin/echo "$(printf "%*s" 131071 "a")">/dev/null
~$ /bin/echo "$(printf "%*s" 131072 "a")">/dev/null
bash: /bin/echo: Argument list too long
```

It is actually the `MAX_ARG_STRLEN` that decides the max size for a single string:

> And as additional limit since 2.6.23, one argument must not be longer than MAX_ARG_STRLEN (131072). 
>   This might become relevant if you generate a long call like "sh -c 'generated with long arguments'". 
>   (pointed out by Xan Lopez and Ralf Wildenhues)

See [this discussion of `ARG_MAX`](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/), under "Number of arguments and maximum length of one argument", and [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120642/) on `unix.stackexchange`.

You can see it in `binfmts.h`:

```
/*
 * These are the maximum length and maximum number of strings passed to the
 * execve() system call.  MAX_ARG_STRLEN is essentially random but serves to
 * prevent the kernel from being unduly impacted by misaddressed pointers.
 * MAX_ARG_STRINGS is chosen to fit in a signed 32-bit integer.
 */
#define MAX_ARG_STRLEN (PAGE_SIZE * 32)
#define MAX_ARG_STRINGS 0x7FFFFFFF

~$ echo $(( $(getconf PAGE_SIZE)*32 )) 
131072
```

You can pass multiple strings of length `131071`:

```
subprocess.check_call(['echo', "a"*131071,"b"*131071], executable='/bin/bash',stdout=open("/dev/null","w"))
```

But a single string arg cannot be longer than 131071 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. One workaround is to pass the Bash commands using the `stdin` of the subprocess. In my testing, I was able to execute single arguments of 16MiB, which is confusing because that should violate all the limits. However, I haven't followed up further because the Bash-based solution was becoming too hairy and I am reverting to pure Python.

Comment: There are a few different ways around it using bash, loops, xargs etc.. depending on what it is you are doing.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673060/split-string-into-strings-by-length) on splitting a string into sub-strings of length n helped me out on this

Answer (score -4):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381241/what-is-the-subprocess-popen-max-length-of-the-args-parameter) other question is similar to yours, but for Windows. As in that scenario, you can bypass any shell limitations by avoiding the `shell=True` option.

Otherwise, you can provide a list of files to `subprocess.Popen()` as done in that scenario, and as suggested by @Aaron Digulla.

Comment: Apparently unlike Windows, the limit does not come from the shell on UNIX.