# Python subprocess with arguments

Tags: python

I run a python script `test.py` by using python subprocess. I want to send two strings `'John', 'Henry'` as argument and read the argument values from the test.py. I want something like this

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'test.py']) #add two names 'John', 'Henry' as argument
```

**test.py**

```
print(name1) #print John
print(name2) #print Henry
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt whatsoever? Given the information you provide, it is extremely unclear how you came up with the first line but are unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.call(['python3', 'test.py', 'John', 'Henry'])
```

and change test.py to look something like this:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
print(sys.argv[2])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. can I pass a big string(several thousand words) as argument. I just tried that but it gives error Argument list too long

Comment: "Argument list too long" is probably not an issue with python, its bash: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29802900/9348376