# How to run a shell script in python from memory?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, sh, popen

The application I'm writing retrieves a shell script through HTTP from Network, I want to run this script in python however I don't want to physically save it to the hard drive because I have its content already in memory, and I would like to just execute it. I have tried something like this:

```
import subprocess

script = retrieve_script()
popen = subprocess.Popen(scrpit, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdOut, stdErr = popen.communicate()

def retrieve_script_content():
    # in reality I retrieve a shell script content from network,
    # but for testing purposes I will just hardcode some test content here
    return "echo command1" + "\n" + "echo command2" + " \n" + "echo command3"
```

This snippet will not work because `subprocess.Popen` expects you to provide only one command at a time.

Are there any alternatives to run a shell script from memory?

Comment: Is this maybe a duplicate of [How to run multiple commands synchronously from one subprocess.Popen command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39721924/how-to-run-multiple-commands-synchronously-from-one-subprocess-popen-command/39722695)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This snippet will not work because subprocess.Popen expects you to provide only one command at a time.

That is not the case. Instead, the reason why it doesn't work is:

1. The declaration of `retrieve_script` has to come before the call
2. You call it `retrieve_script_content` instead of `retrieve_script`
3. You misspelled `script` as `scrpit`

Just fix those and it's fine:

```
import subprocess

def retrieve_script():
    return "echo command1" + "\n" + "echo command2" + " \n" + "echo command3"

script = retrieve_script()
popen = subprocess.Popen(script, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdOut, stdErr = popen.communicate()
print(stdOut);
```

Result:

```
$ python foo.py
command1
command2
command3
```

However, note that this will ignore the shebang (if any) and run the script with the system's `sh` every time.

Comment: It was a typo, but I posted a test code sample here.
I can confirm that running bash scripts like that indeed works on `Linux`. However when I ran similar code on `Windows` it did not work, so you will not be able to run `batch files` like that on `Windows`.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a Unix-like OS? If so, you should be able to [use a virtual filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/how-can-i-create-a-tmpfs-as-a-regular-non-root-user) to make an in-memory file-like object at which you could point `subprocess.Popen`:

```
import subprocess
import tempfile
import os
import stat

def retrieve_script_content():
    # in reality I retrieve a shell script content from network,
    # but for testing purposes I will just hardcode some test content here
    return "echo command1" + "\n" + "echo command2" + " \n" + "echo command3"

content = retrieve_script_content()
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w', delete=False, dir='/dev/shm') as f:
    f.write(content)
    os.chmod(f.name, stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IXUSR)
    # print(f.name)
popen = subprocess.Popen(f.name, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                         shell=True)
stdOut, stdErr = popen.communicate()

print(stdOut.decode('ascii'))
# os.unlink(f.name)
```

prints

```
command1
command2
command3
```

Above I used `/dev/shm` as the virtual filesystem since [Linux systems based on Glibc always have a tmpfs mounted on /dev/shm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26369/3330).
If security is a concern you may wish to [setup a ramfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/325421/3330).

---

One reason why you might want to use a virtual file instead of [passing the script contents directly to `subprocess.Popen`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880158/190597) is that the maximum size for a single string argument is [limited to 131071 bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29802900/190597).

Comment: Thanks, the code will be running on Raspberry Pi `Rasbian Jessie OS`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute multi command script with Popen. Popen only restricts you to one-command string when shell flag is False, yet it is possible to pass a list of commands.  `Popen`'s flag `shell=True` allows for multi-command scripts (it is considered unsecure, though what you are doing - executing scripts from the web - is already very risky).

Comment: We have a web service that provides our application with shell scripts so I know what I'm doing no worries :)

Comment: The answer address general question of how one can execute a downloaded multiline script, though indeed does not goes to reviewing the sample code.