# python - subprocess length limit

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, pipe, thunderbird

I have to create an email from a python script calling:

```python
subprocess.call([
    'thunderbird',
    '-compose',
    "preselectid='{}',to='{}',cc='{}',subject='{}',body='{}'".format(
        preselectid, to, cc, subject, body),
    ])
```

but the email is truncate when the `body` is "too" large.

I know that on Windows there is a limit of 32,768 char ([What is the subprocess.Popen max length of the args parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381241/what-is-the-subprocess-popen-max-length-of-the-args-parameter)) but I'm on Linux (using zsh) and when echoing the string with

```python
subprocess.call([
    'echo',
    "preselectid='{}',to='{}',cc='{}',subject='{}',body='{}'".format(
        preselectid, to, cc, subject, body),
    ])
```

I get the complete and correct email content.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT:
Thanks to @slezica I've found out that copy-pasting the generated email and running the command from command-line I get, anyway, the truncated email (at the 32,303 char).
The problem is `thunderbird`.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  Could you try an even larger body with `echo`, in case the difference in size between "thunderbird -compose" and "echo" crosses some boundary?

Comment: Try running the call from your command-line. This could be a `thunderbird` limitation, or maybe you're hitting the limit with the character difference between `thunderbird -compose` and `echo`

Comment: @slezica nice hint (I'm dumb), I've edited the question

Comment: Not the solution, but running `getconf ARG_MAX` you can obtain the maximum length for shell arguments. If `echo` can take it, this could just be a `thunderbird` limitation

Comment: @slezica: yes, I think too, now, that the problem is thunderbird. The `ARG_MAX` size is 2097152.

Comment: You may want to consider just using the [email library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) in Python directly to avoid these kinds of limitations.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is quasi-answer.

After opening a bug report (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1329312) I was informed that Thunderbird's developers

`implemented an option where you can read the message from a file with message=, see bug 882104. That will be shipping in TB 52, so you could use this now in Earlybird.`